# dot-matrix of chinese character

Tags: arrays, dot-matrix

I want to build a LED dispay of chinese characters, in 16*16.
It already exist in commercial use: [image]

I have tried in python by using converting the chinese character to an image using the librairy PIL  but I only get interesting result with a big size font, which is much more than the 16*16 I want :

[image]

Question : what is the library used for commercial product ( that can be found everywhere in China) that can display in 16*16?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: This is not going to be an answer, but the answers to [this](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/q/5934/5846) and to a lesser extent [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47545359/3904031) might be a little helpful if you still want to try to squeeze PIL