# How to write beta with PIL in python?

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

How to write beta with PIL in python?

I tried:

```
draw.multiline_text((350, 300), 'β', fill=(0, 0, 0), font = font_small)
draw.multiline_text((350, 300), r'$\beta$', fill=(0, 0, 0), font = font_small)
draw.multiline_text((350, 300), u'ß', fill=(0, 0, 0), font = font_small)
draw.multiline_text((350, 300), u'\u03B2', fill=(0, 0, 0), font = font_small)
draw.multiline_text((350, 300), u"ß", fill=(0, 0, 0), font = font_small)
```

Comment: does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11411746/drawing-multilingual-text-using-pil ?

Comment: No, I hope it is similar to my last atmept from the question, right?

Comment: yes, but is your `font_small` a unicode font?

Comment: No, probably not. Thank you you are right. What LM Roman font should I download to have the one that is a Unicode font, please? I treid https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/latin-modern-roman but there is a rectangle after the compilation.

Comment: I got it. CMU-serif is an appropriate font similar to LM Roman with Greek letters available